# Delete all but top 50 rows from DB with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I've been getting a multitude of errors with the request I'm trying to make. I'd like to grab the top 50 ids from my keywords table ordered by count and delete the rest. Any ideas what could be acting up here?

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when making the request...

```
        //1. get ids of top 50
        $this->CI->db->query("SELECT id FROM keywords ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 50");
        $top_fifty = $this->CI->db->get();
        //return $top_fifty;

        //2. loop through and create string of ids "1,2,3,4,5"
        $top_fifty_string = implode(",", $top_fifty);

        // 3. DELETE FROM keywords WHERE id NOT IN(string created in step 2)
        $this->CI->db->query("DELETE FROM keywords WHERE id NOT IN($top_fifty_string)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed function :

```
// //1. get ids of top 50
$top_fifty = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT id FROM keywords ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 50 ");

// //2. array of ids to string "1,2,3,4,5"
$output ="";

foreach ($top_fifty->result() as $k) {
$output .= $k->id . ",";
}
$top_fifty_string = rtrim($output, ",");

// // 3. DELETE FROM keywords WHERE id NOT IN(string created in step 2)
$this->CI->db->query("DELETE FROM keywords WHERE id NOT IN(.$top_fifty_string.)");
```

Comment: Aha, very true. I'm now getting a 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Also, you have to comment your `return $top_fifty;` so the function can go to the end

Comment: I thought I needed to return after making a db request. Does that need to happen somewhere else instead then?

Comment: Nop, you have to generate a result with `->result()` `->result_array()` or `->row()`. `return` is the finality of a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71889/discussion-between-lauren-f-and-adrienxl).

Comment: Try explode the string first before the NOT IN query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it as a subquery:

```
$this->CI->db->query("DELETE FROM keywords WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM keywords ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 50)");
```

Comment: tried that, but it seemed to need the ids to come through as a string

Comment: You can use a sub query this is a much better solution

Comment: @MikeMiller the data doesn't come back in a format that works for the subquery, though.

Comment: Yes it does. It's data from the same table it can't not be in the right format. You can just nest the query instead of use the comma separated values. It's better than the better answer its the correct answer. Your CSV could get too long for the driver to parse, using a nested query will never have this issue